# How can I find a phrase in one column, and output another phrase into a different cell

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to organise my accounts.

I have few columns:  C is my bank's info for each transaction which *could* contain **for example** the word 'petrol' or 'atm' or 'paypal' **among many other key phrases.**

I want to create a macro that goes through column C, searches for '*Paypal', and if it finds it, places 'Paypal' into column D on that same row.

another example - if it finds 'B/CARD PLAT VISA' C58, then I'd like 'Credit Card Payment' to be written in D58.

I'm trying to work it out, based on an old macro I found/adjusted to delete columns!

Something like:

```
Dim c As Range
Dim SrchRng

Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("C1", ActiveSheet.Range("C65536").End(xlUp))
Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find("petrol", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
//SOMETHING GOES HERE?
Loop While Not c Is Nothing
```

?

as you can probably tell, I'm not great at this.

My end goal is to be able to output from these headings how much I've spent and earned in each category each month/year. It should make self employed life slightly easier.

Comment: first you say that column "C"  _"could contain the word 'petrol' or 'atm' or 'paypal'_. Then you say _"if it finds 'B/CARD PLAT VISA' C58"_, which doesn't match any of the preceeding keywords. You should first set down your code specifications properly, then make an attempt at coding it and finally ask for help if in trouble

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear - it contains loads of information - it' a history of my bank account usage - so one entry could simply read 'O2' which is my phone bill, and would need to be added as 'phone bill' in column D. Another Could read "7341 23FEB15 , SAINSBURYS S/MKTS" which is a supermarket near my house, and would be labelled 'Food' in column D.
Most of the account activity is regular, so I would need a rule that looks for 'sainsburys', 'asda', and 'tesco' (all supermarkets near my house) and returns 'food' to D. A rule that finds O2 and returns 'Phone bill' and so on and so forth.

Comment: I have cleared this up in bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you further:

```
Sub OrganiseCategories()

    Dim FoundRange As Range, FirstAddress As String

    With Range("B:B")
      Set FoundRange = .Find("Paypal", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)
      FirstAddress = FoundRange.Address
      Do
        FoundRange.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = "PayPal"
        Set FoundRange = .FindNext(FoundRange)
      Loop While Not FoundRange Is Nothing And FoundRange.Address <> FirstAddress

    End With

End Sub
```

Ron de Bruin has a nice page on this:
http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win006.htm

Comment: I'm getting a "Object variable or With block variable not set" on     FirstAddress = FoundRange.Address

Comment: This is due to you providing a search-string to look for that you do not have in your to-search-range.  I.e. if none of the entries in column "B" are named "Paypal", then "FoundRange" will remain "Nothing" (i.e. 'not set'), thus returning this error-message.  You just have to find a way to deal with these situations by either: 1. Error-handling, 2. Making sure your search-string is always something that will be found.

Comment: I see the problem now ! After correcting the B:B to C1:C500 and giving an EXACT match - it worked! However, I needed the search to not be exact! so when I want to tag items as petrol - I would like both the cell "12AUG15 , SAINSBURYS PETROL" ,and the cell "04SEP15 , ASDA PETROL/UPT" to both be counted! 

With some googling - I think I need to use instr rather than find? or do they need to be used together?

Answer (score 1):

OK! So with the help of CoRrRan, some self-recording of macros and a little google, I've managed to create exactly what I needed.

```
Sub OrganiseCategories()

Dim FoundRange As Range, FirstAddress As String, Searchterm As Variant,     Searchresult As Variant

Searchterm = InputBox("What term would you like to search for?")
Searchresult = InputBox("What category would you like to set for this term?")
    With Range("C:C")
  Set FoundRange = .Find(What:=Searchterm, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
  FirstAddress = FoundRange.Address
  Do
    FoundRange.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Searchresult

    Set FoundRange = .FindNext(FoundRange)
  Loop While Not FoundRange Is Nothing And FoundRange.Address <> FirstAddress

End With

End Sub
```

This gives me an input box to enter a non-exact search term, and an input box to  choose a category to place the search result in: much easier than changing the code each time I want to make a new search. I may create multiple 'default' searches for terms like petrol, visa, paypal etc. without the input boxes, as a base in a separate macro.